# Make multiple plots at once

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a df that looks like this:

```
         date        group         score    origin    ...
0        1           group1            1    0         ...
1        1           group2            2    1         ...
2        2           group2            5    2         ...
3        2           group1            2    3         ...
4        1           group1            1    3         ...
5        1           group2            2    2         ...
6        2           group2            5    1         ...
7        2           group1            2    0         ...
```

and I need to make multiple, separate line plots. One for each unique value of `origin`, with `date` on the x axis and `score` on the y.

Currently my code looks like this:

```py
sns.lineplot(x='date', y='score', hue='group', style_order=order, data=df)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
```

Instead of running this multiple times, I'd like to be able to have 1 statement that produces separate plots for each unique value of origin. I've tried a few variations of `groupby` or `subplot` but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`seaborn.FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) for simple control over these types of plots:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row='origin', hue='group')
g.map(sns.lineplot, 'date', 'score')
```

[out]

[image]

Comment: How do I add the `hue` argument to this. When I try g = `sns.FacetGrid(GroupObservation_merged, col="origin", col_wrap=5, height=4.5)
g = g.map(plt.plot, "date", "score", hue="Group", marker=".")` I get an error

Comment: I've updated the example, pass `hue` argument to the FacetGrid constructor